# Dynamic Form Collapsible with individually collapse Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
  <div class="multi-fields">
    <div class="multi-field">
      <a class="panel-heading collapsed" role="tab" id="headingOne" 
         data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-parent="#accordion" 
         href="#collapseOne" 
         aria-expanded="true" 
         aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <h4>Add Data</h4>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i>
      </a>
      <div id="collapseOne"
           class="panel-collapse collapse in"
           role="tabpanel"
           aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Content Here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
</div>
```

and the following JavaScript using jQuery:

```
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function () {
  var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
  $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function (e) {
    $('.multi-field:first-child', wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
  });
  $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function () {
    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1) {
      $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is, when collapsible is only one the `href="#collapseOne` will target `tabpanel collapseOne`, but when I've added one or more multi-fields the `href="#collapseOne"` will target all `tabpanel`'s `id` because it has same name.

Is there any way to make the `#href` and `tabpanel`'s `id` different each time we press the 'Add field' button or using this alternative script at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhZVn/)?